# Is it possible to use the number of current replacement in String.replaceAll?

Tags: java, regex, string

Is it possible to make `String.replaceAll` put the number (count) of the current replacement into the replacement being made?

So that `"qqq".replaceAll("(q)", "something:$1 ")` would result in `"1:q 2:q 3:q"`?

Is there anything that I can replace *something* in the code above with, to make it resolve into the current substitution count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
StringBuffer resultString = new StringBuffer();
String subjectString = new String("qqqq");
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("q");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
int i = 1;
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
   regexMatcher.appendReplacement(resultString, i+":"+regexMatcher.group(1)+" ");
   i++;
}
regexMatcher.appendTail(resultString);
System.out.println(resultString);
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/JnRZb)

Comment: Thanks, although the answer to my question is *NO* your method is the closest match

Answer (score 1):

No, not with the `replaceAll` method. The only backreference is `\n` where n is the n'th capturing group matched.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create your own **replaceAll()** method.

This helps you:

```
public class StartTheClass 
{       
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    String string="wwwwww";
    System.out.println("Replaced As: \n"+replaceCharector(string, "ali:", 'w'));    
}

public static String replaceCharector(String original, String replacedWith, char toReplaceChar)
{
    int count=0;
    String str = "";
    for(int i =0; i < original.length(); i++)
    {
        
        if(original.charAt(i) == toReplaceChar)
        {
            str += replacedWith+(count++)+" ";//here add the 'count' value and some space;
        }
        else
        {
            str += original.charAt(i);
        }
        
    }
    return str;
}   
}
```

The output I got is:

> Replaced As:
>
> ali:0 ali:1 ali:2 ali:3 ali:4 ali:5